# "Find" function for largest number?

Tags: browser

Does anyone have any idea how it would be possible search through large webpages with lots of numbers to find the largest number, then second-largest?

Something like the "Find" function does, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript and jQuery, so you can traverse through each DOM element, store them in a data structure and sort. Then print it somewhere.